¿Como mantener la sesión de microsoft graph abierta en un programa java?
Estoy haciendo un programa en java con el que pretendo usar la API de one drive para subir y descargar archivos. Por lo que entiendo, primero obtiene un tocken con Oauth2 y despues se pueden hacer las consultas.
De momento el codigo que tengo es el básico y me gustaría saber que puedo hacer para que el usuario no tenga que iniciar sesion cada vez que abre el programa sino que se guarden los tocken en un archivo o algo asi y se renueven al abrir la aplicacion otra vez ya que tengo entendido que caducan cada 2h. Este es mi código:
package com.example;

import com.microsoft.graph.serviceclient.GraphServiceClient;
import com.azure.identity.InteractiveBrowserCredential;
import com.azure.identity.InteractiveBrowserCredentialBuilder;
import com.microsoft.graph.models.User;

public class App 
{
    private static final String CLIENT_ID = "***";
    private static final String tenantId = "consumers";

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        try{
            final String[] scopes = new String[] {"User.Read", "Files.Read.All"};
            final InteractiveBrowserCredential credential = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialBuilder()
            .clientId(CLIENT_ID).tenantId(tenantId).redirectUrl("http://localhost").build();

            if (null == scopes || null == credential) {
                throw new Exception("Unexpected error");
            }

            final GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(credential, scopes);

            User me = graphClient.me().get();
            System.out.printf("Hello %s, your ID is %s%n", me.getDisplayName(), me.getId());
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
}

A lo mejor parece una cosa simple pero no entiendo como obtener los tockens de GraphClient o si existe otra manera cambiando la clase que obtiene las credenciales. Y sobretodo tampoco sé si por ejemplo al guardar las claves y recuerarlas a la semana siguen sirviendo para algo o no.
Gracias por adelantado.
